# How to change migrate mySQL database from 5.7.14 to version 5.6 or 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, database

I mistakenly created my website on localhost which is running mySQL 5.7.14.

Unfortunately the version on my webhost is currently 5.5, and the highest version I can get up to is 5.6.

I found [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html) but it truly seems a bit out of my depth due to my limited knowledge with mySQL.

I am hoping someone could simplify the directions or even convert the database for me?

I can include the database if needed.

Comment: did you dump the SQL structure and data and tried to import it to lower version MySQL ? what errors did it output ?

Comment: I am seriously at a loss. I cannot even get a different version of mySQL to run on my localhost...

Comment: by the way I am using WAMP

Comment: you can get multiple MySQL running as long as you configure it properly with different ports and have PHP connect to the server you want. haven't used wamp I assume it doesn't offer an way to use alternative versions. Try downloading from MySQL website  the version you want. Also you can work with MySQL workbench it sure will make it easier for you to work with MySQL server.